# best scripting language to develop rational clearcase plugin to extract some functionalities

Tags: python, perl, clearcase

I just want to know about clearcase. Basically i want to write some application which will extract some files from clearcase vobs. Right now i am not getting any clue that which scripting language like python or perl i should use. basically i am looking for perl scripting for that. I also want to know is there any proper document or book available for clearcase exposed api list and documentation.

Thanks in advance,

Abhijit

Answer (score 1):

The official API is **[cleartool](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_hood_cleartool_cli.htm)**, the command line interface which contains *all* ClearCase commands.
You can call cleartool commands from a Perl script (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase/375437#375437))

An example of a [Perl library able to call cleartool command is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273200/how-can-i-interact-with-clearcase-from-perl/2273896#2273896).

The other scripting interface is [ClearCase Automation Library (CAL)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21123249).
See [this question for an example of CAL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193805/get-clearcase-snapshot-views-via-clearcase-automation-library-cal/1193934#1193934) based on Perl.

Note that in any case, you will need ClearCase views ([snapshot or dynamic ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378)) to access Vobs elements (versioned files or directories).