# Need help with CM API (ClearCase)

Tags: java, clearcase, build-automation, clearquest

I need to get particular Stream( perhaps with Activity) from Clear Case (7.1.1 server) and store it on local machine. Let me come up with a User Story:
"I'm as admin of central build system want to automate "getting code" step from Clear Case repository for corresponding SCR or IR so that latest and greatest code was on build server".

I'm looking for help with CM API. It looks like it can handle it but I lost in API...luck of support on Rational ClearCase forum brought me here. Few cents would be a gold for me. Thanks.

-Roman.

Comment: More specific technical question - how I can get a snapshot of stream to a brand new folder? (by means of CM API (CcProvider <-> Proxy <-> Location <-> New Props(?) <-> Resource <-> Content <-> Repository)...I'm trying different approaches, but this API has tons of available methods, and I'm not exactly sure about sequence of actions that should be done as well as what desire props should I pass as a flags to myStream.doCopy(Location, flags, feedback); - if this is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like all you need to build an UCM view on that stream (preferably a dynamic view), in order to select the LATEST version of the branch corresponding to said Stream.

You will see here [an example of CAL script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193805/get-clearcase-snapshot-views-via-clearcase-automation-library-cal/1193934#1193934) for getting a view (but not for making one).
That being said, a simple cleartool command is enough, as illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367635/how-do-i-create-a-snapshot-view-of-some-project-or-stream-in-clearcase/1367656#1367656): no need for CAL script.

Comment: I already have some code with CM API where I refresh existing on server views and it would be easy to handle everything from java without doing scripting on perl. Besides, we don't support dynamic views, and we don't have installed cleartool on a build server (ClearCase and ClearQuest servers are not the same as build server). I heard about CCRC_CLI which is analogue of cleartool, but if it is possible I would like to solve this problem by means of CM API.(from java). Thanks.

Comment: @br00ks: CCRC_CLI is only valid if you are a client making request to a CCRC (ClearCase Remote Client) *server* (i.e. a Web Server which, in turn, will make request to the actual CC Vob server). For classic client-ClearCase server (not CCRC), CM API or a simple `Java Process.execute("cleartool ...")` is required.